# Spark Scala Programming for not serializable objects and functions

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, rdd, serializable

I have a "Task not serializable" Exception when I run a Spark Scala program with

- Spark RDDs is of not serializable type (java class)
- called functions are from a not serializable class (java class, again)

my code is something like this

```
object Main{
    def main(args : Array(String){
        ...
        var rdd = sc.textFile(filename)
                  .map(line => new NotSerializableJClass(line)).cache() 
        //rdd is RDD[NotSerializableJClass]
        ...
        var test = new NotSerializableJPredicate()
        rdd = rdd.filter(elem => test.test(elem))
        //throws TaskNotSerializable on test Predicate class
    }
}
```

I notice that i can resolve the second part with

```
rdd = rdd.filter(elem => (new NotSerializableJPredicate()).test(elem))
```

but I still get that Exception for the class of the objects in RDDs. And I would in another way also the second part in another way just because I don't want to create a great number of PredicateClass's object.

Can you help me? How can I go forward with non-serializable class?

Comment: Is `NotSerializableJClass` a third party class or a class defined in your application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDDs must be serializable so you cannot create an RDD of a non serializable class.

For your predicate, you could write it using mapPartitions.

```
rdd.mapPartitions{
  part => 
    val test = new NotSerializableJPredicate()
    part.filter{elem => test.test(elem)}
   }
```

mapPartitons will run once per partition, so it allows you to instantiate non-serializable classes on the executor, but it only needs to do it once per partition rather than for every record.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the general rules that has helped me avoid Task Serialization Issue:

If you are calling a method of any class from your code;Spark will need to serialize the entire class containing the method.Ways to go around can be any of the following :
 a> Declare the method as a function variable in NotSerializableClass; so instead of writing : 
def foo(x:Int)={blah blah} try using val foo = (x:Int)=>{blah blah }
So; spark no longer needs to serialize the entire class now.
b> Refactoring the code to extract the relevant portions in a separate class may be the way to go in certain cases.
c>Mark objects in the class which are actually not necessary for the job as @transient and mark the class Serializable